# Laravel 'can' middleware return error 500 "This action is unauthorized"

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

i'm trying to create a website based on laravel framework. I'm stuck in permission control with Policy. This is my code:
+ Policies Register in `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
        Category::class => CategoryPolicy::class
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        try {
            Permission::all()->each(function($permission) {
                Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use($permission) {
                    return $user->hasPermission($permission->name);
                });
            });
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::notice('Unable to register gates. Either no database connection or no permissions table exists.');
        }
    }
}
```

- User Policy in `App\Policies\UserPolicy`

```
class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function view(User $user, User $target_user)
    {
        return $user->id === $target_user->id;
    }

}
```

- Api Route in `routes/api.php`

```
Route::get('/users', 'Api\UserController@getUsers')->middleware('can:view-users');
Route::get('/users/{user_id}', 'Api\UserController@getUser')->middleware('can:view-users');
Route::put('/users/{user_id}', 'Api\UserController@updateUser')->middleware('can:edit-users');
```

- User Controller in `App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController`

```
    public function getUsers(UserRequest $request) {
        $users = $this->userRepository->getAll();
        $this->authorize('view', $user);
        return response($users, 200);
    }

    public function getUser(UserRequest $request, $user_id) {
        $user = $this->userRepository->find($user_id);
        $this->authorize('view', $user);
        return response($user, 200);
    }
```

- When I try to get data by using 2 url above, it returned error `500 Internal Server Error` even when user is authenticated :

```
{
    "error": "This action is unauthorized."
}
```

- I tried to log result and found that error come from middleware `can` or `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize`.

Code line:

`$this->gate->authorize($ability, $this->getGateArguments($request, $models));` in `handle()` function throw error above.

- After hours searching, I could not figure out solution.

Anyone can point out my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. After hours reading source code in library, I figured out problem. I used `api` guard for my app without `passport` module. Thus, variable `$userResolver` in `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate` class could not be set to authenticated user and got `null` value. To solve this problem, I created my own `Authorize` middleware instead of laravel middleware `Authorize` and use `Auth::guard('api')->user()` to get authenticated user.